# How do I set fixed spacing for side by side graphs in python using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, spacing, graphing

I am trying to generate two side by side 3D graphs in python using matplotlib. I am trying to use a [stereoscopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereoscopy) approach to allow users to view the depth of the 3D output better. Where I'm running into problems is that for this to work the two graphs need to be fixed 6cm apart (to work with the specific equipment I have). Below is a link to a picture of what I have so far for output (because I don't have the rep for an actual picture yet). I've played around with doing the tight layout option and tweeking the padding but this seems to be a relative padding that changes with the size of the image. Is there a way I can I lock these two plots 6cm apart from each-other, or is it always going to be relative?

[image: Side by Side Plots Currently]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about laying them out in a three subplot format and then putting something in that middle space that is forced to 6 cm?

Comment: That could be a good workaround if there isn't a way to do this automatically. Thanks!